# how to save HashSet into a plain text file in Scala

Tags: scala, io, hashset

For example, I have a HashSet and want to save it to file like txt or csv and so on.

```
val slotidSet: util.HashSet[String] = new util.HashSet[String](1)
slotidSet.add("100")
slotidSet.add("105")
slotidSet.add("102")
slotidSet.add("103")
```

How to save this HashSet into a plain text file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the structure you want in the saved file? Just one line per element? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the work

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
import java.util

Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), slotidSet.asScala.mkString(",").getBytes)
```

Output is

```
100,102,103,105
```

Now it's just up to you to choose format, in this case all the elements are just concatenated with `,`. In cases where you need to work with files in Scala/Java, Java NIO is a good place to start.